# Logistic Regression - Odds & log of odds

Tags: logistic-regression

***ln(p1−p)=β0+β1X***

The equation of line in the above equation denotes that the log of odds is linearly related to the predictor variables.

Why is *log of odds* linearly related to the predictor variables, but not the plain **odds**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For understanding this first we will have to look at the maths of logistic regression.

The equation of linear regression is given by :
P(y|x;w) = Sigmoid(wTx + b)

Now if we take log on both sides and folow the match in the image below, it clearly show **why log of odds linearly related to the predictor variables**

[image]

After step 6, shown in above image if you take log on both sides, it becomes log of odd

```
    i.e ***ln(p/1-p) is linearly related wTx +b***
```

Image Ref : https://ayearofai.com/rohan-6-follow-up-statistical-interpretation-of-logistic-regression-e78de3b4d938